Can chronal shift be applied to yourself?
One of my player is a wizard with chronurgy magic.
Chronal shift states that:
"At 2nd level, you can magically exert limited control over the flow of time around a creature. As a reaction, after you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can force the creature to reroll. You make this decision after you see whether the roll succeeds or fails. The target must use the result of the second roll.
You can use this ability twice, and you regain any expended uses when you finish a long rest."
My question is, can the player use it for himself, on is own roll affecting him?
Thanks a lot
Bonus Question:
Can he stack it with the Lucky feat and if yes, in which order would you have it? I feel like lucky should arrive first as it's before the outcomes is decided while chronal shift is after the outcome is decided.

I would suggest you split this into 2 separate questions, or you will likely see this get closed. Also welcome to the stack

When I said split into 2 questions I see what you did, but what I meant was remove the reference to lucky entirely, and post a brand new question with "how does lucky interact with x".

Taking the text of the spell, "you" is included in the creatures that can trigger a reroll:

As a reaction, after you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, an ability check, or a saving throw, you can force the creature to reroll.

So yes, the spell can be used for yourself.
